# Odoo: Unable to use a closed cursor

Tags: odoo-14

I am trying to call a function after a response has been returned from a http request:

```
class SomeAPIEndpoint(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/api', type='json')
    def controller(self, **kwargs):
        data = self.function1(request)
        with api.Environment.manage():
            env = api.Environment(request.env.cr, request.env.user.id, request.env.context)
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.function2, args=(env,))
            t.start()
        return data


    def function1(self, request):
        # should return the response 
        data = request.env['some.model'].search([])
        # work with the data here ...
        return data

    def function2(self, env):
        # should not stop the response
        # triggers a cron job that gets new data from a service
        # and stores the data in some.model
        cron = env['ir.cron'].search([('id', '=', 1)])
        cron.with_user(cron.user_id).with_context(lastcall=cron.lastcall).ir_actions_server_id.run()
```

I want `function1` to be executed and return the response and `function2` to be executed after the response.

But I get `Unable to use a closed cursor.`

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeAPIEndpoint(http.Controller):
@http.route('/api', type='json')
def controller(self, **kwargs):
    data = self.function1(request)

    threaded_delay = threading.Thread(
        target=self.function2,
        args=(request.env.cr.dbname))
    threaded_delay.setDaemon(True)
    threaded_delay.start()

    return data


def function1(self, request):
    # should return the response 
    data = request.env['some.model'].search([])
    # work with the data here ...
    return data

def function2(self, dbname=False):
    # should not stop the response
    # triggers a cron job that gets new data from a service
    # and stores the data in some.model
    with api.Environment.manage(), registry(dbname).cursor() as new_cr:
        env = api.Environment(new_cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})


        cron = env['ir.cron'].search([('id', '=', 1)])
        cron.with_user(cron.user_id).with_context(lastcall=cron.lastcall).ir_actions_server_id.run()

        new_cr.commit()
```